# echo $? doesn't work when executed remotely

Tags: bash, scripting, shell-scripting

When I execute a command as below it gives me an output as expected but when I run the same command on remote server it always gives me `echo $?` as `0`.

```
locally
# <some command>
# echo $?

Remotely
# ssh server " <some command >; echo $? "
```

Now in case of remote execution I always get `0` as `echo $?` output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `$?` is evaluated before the command is sent to the remote machine. Effectively, you are sending the command `echo 0`. Try

```
ssh server ' <some command >; echo $? '
```

As Michael Hampton points out, single quotes prevent evaluating variables etc. before sending them to the remote command, while double quotes allow that.

Comment: To be clear, you should use the single quote `'` instead of the double quote `"`.